# mass-change email addresses on git with github

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have recently cloned an hg repo to git so i can post it on github. Lots of the email addresses are wrong and I would like to use git rebase to change them before anyone forks this project. If i change them how do I go about pushing the new, completely rebased repo to github? can I just rebase and then  `git push`? do i have to delete the project first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. You need to use `git push -f` (or `--force`) in order to overwrite the old history.

---

On a completely different note: why would you "*like to use `git rebase`*" to change the committer e-mail addresses instead of `git filter-branch --env-filter`?

Comment: i was using the term rebase to include anything that rewrites the commits.

Comment: after doing this github lists both an Author and a Committer for each commit?

Comment: @Arthur: github shows both identities when they are different. When using `git filter-branch --env-filter`, be sure to update GIT_COMMITTER_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL, as well as GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL.

Comment: Thanks Chris, now it's cleanly up on github AND google code :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation just yet to comment on Jörg's post, but github has a nice shell script using `git filter-branch --env-filter` that helped me do the same thing at http://help.github.com/changing-author-info/. This is an example of what the other commenters on Jörg's post were talking about. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is the following:

- Create a .mbox file which contains all the patches since the repo's inception: `git format-patch --stdout --root > repo_history.mbox`
- Edit the `repo_history.mbox` file, changing all e-mail addresses as you see fit. It could be as easy as `perl -pi~ -e's/oldemail\@host\.org/newemail\@newhost\.com/gi' repo_history.mbox`
- Create a new repo: `mkdir ~/newrepo; cd ~/newrepo; git init`
- Apply the previous mbox's changes to the new repo: `git am /path/to/repo_history.mbox`

I just tested it on a repo of mine, and it seems like the above has done the trick.
Let me know if you'd like more details.

**Important**: You should only do this *before* you ever publish that repository, and not once other people have already pulled from it -- I see your question states that already, but this is just to reiterate the importance of this :)